# How to grant access to a project for all members in the organization?

Tags: azure-devops

The `Project Collection Valid Users` group contains a list of all users and groups that have access to a project in the Azure DevOps platform.

Unfortunately, it seems that you can't add this group to another group that has access to another project.

I need all members of the organization to be able to access a specific project.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Make a group in Azure AD. Grant that group access.

Answer (score 2):

When you create new group in a project. The new group will be automatically added to the `Project Valid Users` group.

And `Project Valid Users` of each Project is automatically added to `Project Collection Valid Users` group of the Organization, which means the `Project Collection Valid Users` group is the parent group of all groups. That's why you cannot add this group to another group.

One of the workaround to allow all organization members to access a specific project is to create a new group(ie. `AllOrganizationUsers` in below screenshot) to include all the users in the **Permissions** page under **Security** section in **Organization Settings**.

Then you can add this new group created in the organization Setting page to a existing group(or create new group in project permissions setting page)of the project Permissions page.

[image]

Comment: This approach would require that administrators manually add every new member to this "AllOrganizationUsers" group when they are added to the organization, correct? The beauty of the Project Collection Valid Users group is that it naturally includes all members of the organization who have access to one or more projects, though I do recognize that it cannot be leveraged to satisfy the requirements here.

Comment: @AdamChubbuck I am afraid Yes, Azure devops doesnot support bulk add users yet. There is user voice which has been submitted about this feature. You can vote it up [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/338059/add-the-feature-to-bulk-add-users-to-an-azure-devo.html). If you are using Azure AD directory. You can bulk import the users to a group in Azure AD. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/groups-bulk-import-members).